# JSON-LD for more products in one page

Tags: json-ld

If I have more products in one page, how can I set JSON-LD?

```html
<article>
Our car dealership is here to make sure your vehicle always performs at its best. We provide a diverse range of services to the manufacturer’s high standard, and you’ll receive a nu.....
</article>

<article>
ALFA ROME 2.0 
<img ... />
</article>

<article>
ALFA ROME 3.0
<img ... /> 

<img ... />
</article>
```

Comment: Do you want to use the vocabulary Schema.org? -- What did you try? Where exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

yes i want use schema.org.

i have tried to do this for each car:

```js
<script type="application/ld+json">
{

"@context":"http://schema.org",
 "@type":"Car",
 "name": "Alfa Romeo Giulietta 1.6 JTDm",
 "model": "Giulietta",
 "brand":"alfa romeo",
 "fuelType":"Diesel",
 "vehicleEngine":"Diesel - 4 cilindri in linea - Cilindrata: 1598 cm3 - 4 Valvole per cilindro - Sovralimentato - Potenza max: 88 kw (120CV) a 4.000 giri/min - Coppia max 32,6 kgm (320,0 Nm) a 1.750 giri/min - Euro 6 (715/2007 - 692/2008) - Potenza Fiscale 17 CV",
 "description" : "Alfa Romeo Giulietta 1.6 JTDm - 2 120 CV Distinctive (05/2015)",
 "image":"assets/img/annunci/alfa-romeo-giulietta-distinctive.jpg",
 "offers":{  
 "@type": "Offer",
    "priceCurrency": "EUR",
    "price": "20.850"
 }
}

</script>


<script type="application/ld+json">
{

"@context":"http://schema.org",
 "@type":"Car",
 "name": "FIAT Nuova Panda ",
 "model": "new panda",
 "brand":"fiat",
 "fuelType":"Benzina",
 "vehicleEngine":"Benzina - 4 cilindri in linea - Cilindrata: 1242 cm3 - 2 Valvole per cilindro - Potenza max: 51 kw (69CV) a 5.500 giri/min - Coppia max 20,4 kgm (102,0 Nm) a 3.000 giri/min - Euro 6 (715/2007 - 692/2008) Potenza Fiscale 14 CV",
 "description" : "FIAT Nuova Panda 1.2 Lounge (07/2014)",
 "image":"assets/img/annunci/fiat-500-x-1.6-pop-star.jpg"
}


</script>
```

....

but is correct (if one page have more car)? the real page is auto-calanca.it/promozioni.